# How do I handle a Windows Authentication using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am attempting to automate a process using selenium with Java. 
I am trying to navigate to a URL, which the test does do. A screen pops out over the top of Firefox asking for a user name and password. When this screen pops out, firebug stops working and I cannot get any information about this screen.

How do I handle a modal dialogue with Selenium, when I cannot find anything about it?

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Firefox with CTRL+U you can view the page source..Try that and search for username or password so you can locate the id's you need.

Comment: If it is a real dialog box, it's an 'alert' and Selenium2 has a feature for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, that you are trying to get to HTTP Authentification protected page. Try getting here like this:

```
driver.get("http://username:password@your-site.com");
```

Where `driver` is assumed as healthy and living instance of `WebDriver`

Answer (score 0):

This actually did not work, the dialog still displays. Instead of running the tests in Firefox as I had wanted I ran them in IE which was using NTLM so I didn't need to input my information.